# Method addSelect does not exist

Tags: methods, controller, laravel-5

I'm getting this error message when I try to do a addSelect method in Laravel 5.2

Any ideas?

> BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 74:
>   Method addSelect does not exist.

---

Here is the function in my controller

public function summaryOfMembersTable()
    {

```
    $members = MotherProfile::select('last_name')
        ->orderBy('last_name','ASC')
        ->distinct()
        ->get();

    $count = $members->count(); 

    $mothers = MotherProfile::select(DB::raw('count(*) as user_count, gender'))     
        ->where('gender', '<>', 'F')
        ->groupBy('gender')
        ->get();

    $fullnames = $members
        ->addSelect('first_name')
        ->orderBy('last_name','ASC')
        ->distinct()
        ->get();


    $data = [];     
    $data['members'] = $members;
    $data['memberCount'] = $count;
    $data['mothers'] = $mothers;
    $data['fullnames'] = $fullnames;

    return view( 'user/masterlist/summary-of-members', $data);  

}
```

My blade:

Total is {{ $memberCount }}

```
        @foreach ($fullnames as $fullname)
        {{ $fullname }}<br>
        @endforeach
        <hr>
        <div class="page-header" style="text-align:center;">
          <h3 class="pageHeader">
            List of Members
            <br>
          </h3>
        </div>          
        <div class="row">           
            <table class="table table-bordered" style="text-align: left;">
                    <tr>                            
                        <th></th>
                        <th>Full Name (Last, First, Middle)</th>                            
                        <th>KLC</th>
                        <th>Category</th>
                        <th>Mem Type</th>
                        <th>Mem Status</th>                         
                        <th>Date Baptized</th>
                        <th>Mother in Spirit</th>
                        <th>Encoder</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tbody>

                    </tbody>
            </table></div>
```

Comment: any piece of code? one that calls the addSelect..? and where does this addSelect called?

Comment: send your code.

Comment: Sure, will edit this now. I thought this is a common laravel problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are getting a collection instead of an object.  **addSelect** method belong to builder object not to collection.  So remove **get()** from your query and you'll be fine.

```
 $members = MotherProfile::select('last_name')
        ->orderBy('last_name','ASC')
        ->distinct()
        ->get();
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the solution. Is there a way for me to know which methods belong to collection and which to object builder? Thanks

Comment: Ok, I think I can find that out. Thanks again @Rodrane, you're way awesome!

Answer (score 0):

```
$members = MotherProfile::select('id','last_name')
        ->orderBy('last_name','ASC')
        ->distinct()
        ->addSelect(DB::raw("'value' as nameFake"))->get();
```

**before** to get()